# In Kendo UI,How to make the background-color of the scheduler's tiltle transparent?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler, kendo-ui-mvc

I have set the color of the title in the scheduler,and do not want the  background-color.But it show me the default background-color 'blue'.How to make the background-color transparent ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by default Kendo sets a background image, so changing the background-color  doesn't help. In your CSS set

```
.k-header { background: transparent; }
```

This will affect any other Kendo controls you have on your page, so you can make your selector more specific.